# PDFBox extract labels of form pdf

Tags: java, pdfbox, pdf-form

I have form PDF file as shown in image.[FORM_PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSlon.png)

Using PDFBox in Java I have retrieved text of the form fields.
My Code:

```
    File file = new File("example.pdf");
    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);
    PDDocumentCatalog catalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDAcroForm form = catalog.getAcroForm();
    PDFieldTree fields = form.getFieldTree();

    for (PDField field : fields) {
        Object value = field.getValueAsString();
        String name = field.getPartialName();
        System.out.print(name);
        System.out.print(" = ");
        System.out.print(value);
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Output :

- Given Name Text Box = Jignesh
- Family Name Text Box = Jignesh
- House nr Text Box = xyz
- Address 2 Text Box = pqr

---

I want below also to be retrieved

1. Given Name:
2. Family Name:
3. Address 1:

as

- Given Name Text = Given Name:
- Family Name Text = Family Name:
- House nr Text = Address 1:
- Address 2 Text = Address 2:

---

Since above were form fields all fields were retrieved easily. I want to extract even the labels of the form, since I want to map both of them.

Please help with the same.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by *static textfields*? Your code prints the content of all fields. Everything else on the page is one big block of page content.

Comment: Sorry for my wrong English, I wanted to write: I want to extract form labels and nothing as such static textfields..

Comment: Labels of form fields are part of the regular page content. You can extract page content text using the `PdfTextStripper` or subclasses of it, e.g. `PdfTextStripperByArea`. But you've got to know where the labels are in relation to the field and code accordingly. In your case they are left of it for text fields.